# Monthly View with Dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, for-loop

I am using DayPilot to create a monthly view of events

Using this [tutorial](https://mvc.daypilot.org/monthly-mvc-calendar-with-dropdown-navigation-jquery/) I have created a calendar view of events, but the dropdownlist only accounts for future dates.  How do I set up the for loop so that it starts at January of the current year.

Here is the for loop:

```
@for (var d = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1); d < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(15); d = d.AddMonths(1))
{
    <option value="@d.ToString("s")">@d.ToString("MMMM yyyy")</option>
}
```

This results in:

> April 2017 - July 2018

I would like to keep the 15 months past the current month, but would like the dropdown to start at January 2017.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe `1` instead of `DateTime.Today.Month`?

Comment: @Sxntk Wow I can't believe I didn't think of that.. I was thinking of the rule.. good lord haha not enough coffee this morning. post it as an answer!

Comment: We are here to help in those moments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the count on January (1) instead of `DateTime.Today.Month`

```
@for (var d = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1); d < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(15); d = d.AddMonths(1))
{
    <option value="@d.ToString("s")">@d.ToString("MMMM yyyy")</option>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go back to 14 months back using `AddMonths(-14)` and use that as start month for your loop.

```
<select>
    @{ var start = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-14); }
        @for (var d = start; d < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1); d = d.AddMonths(1))
        {
        <option value="@d.ToString("s")">@d.ToString("MMMM yyyy")</option>
        }
</select>
```

`DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1)` will give you next month and the expression `d < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1)` in the loop ensure that your loop ends after printing current month.

15 months(back) from current month(April) will give you a month range starting from Feb, Not Jan. If you want to include Jan, you need 16 months.

If you do not want 15 months back, But want to a specific month as start (Ex : JAN 2016), You can use the below `DateTime` contructor to get that date as start.

```
var start = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01);
```